# twitter4j search returns non matching tweets

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-search

I'm using Twitter4j to query past tweets. My question is when I look at the tweet text of the downloaded tweets, I could see tweets from here and there which doesn't contain my query keyword. I can't understand why this is happening. Below is the code that I use:

```
        String queryStr = "mixer"
        Query query = new Query( queryStr );
        query.setCount( 100 );
        QueryResult result = twitter.search( query );

        do
        {
            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
            for ( Status tweet : tweets )
            {

                if (tweet.getLang().equals( "en" ))
                {                       
                    System.out.println( "Tweet: " + tweet.getText().replace( "\n", " " ) + tweet.getCreatedAt() );
                }

            }
            query = result.nextQuery();
            if ( query != null )
            {                   
                result = twitter.search( query );
            }
        } while ( query != null );
```

For example, when my query was "mixer" I got tweets like below:

> RT @onedirection: Is there anyone on earth who hasn't seen #DragMeDownVideo yet? #JourneyToMars http://t.co/3MH9SB6pil http://t.co/XRWrlbRH…
>
> RT @lightpinkhoran: one direction in one vine https://t.co/fvqjAxZ1yZ

Comment: Even through twitter.com search this appears to be the case. Perhaps there's some other meta data in the `Status` that's causing the match?

Comment: I'm wondering what kind of metadata. maybe the content inside the url..?

Comment: I was thinking it could be in one of the other attributes on a [`Status`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html) object. I'm not sure though.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: not really. I guess they look for content inside URLs as well as usernames for potential keyword matches